# storing preferences within the app to be used later

Tags: objective-c, memory, variables, plist

How can I store a large float value, like 0.00032012 in the app?? I need to store that number, so when someone click a save preferences button, it stores a variable. Then when I relaunch the app, it will remember that number and post it in a text field.

I was thinking of using plist, but how can I store variables in the plist??? Examples?

Any ideas???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [user defaults guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i):

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// save:
[defs setDouble:0.0032 forKey:@"myNumber"];
// load:
double d = [defs doubleForKey:@"myNumber"];
```

Answer (score 3):

[UserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i) is the best way to store preferences like this. You can store Cocoa's built-in `NSNumber` objects by default, or you can use [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you need more storage space.

Comment: See Georg Fritzsche's answer. He has updated with sample code now.